Can I remove xml definition in DoxygenLayout.xml
In Doxygen 1.11.0 (probably also in previous versions, I haven't checked) the DoxygenLayout.xml generated by running doxygen -l contains the following first line:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

This line is however causing me issues with the process which generates the documentation. Can I remove it ? Is it an optional line ?

What kind of problems does it cause? Why does the process you are using use that file? I don't think you can remove it as at that moment it is not a valid xml files anymore.

Unfortunately, it is a process I have no access to which is failing, and indicates this line as the problem, but I cannot find out anything more about it other than that. My understanding was that UTF-8 is the default value, so if one does not include that line, it defaults to use UTF-8 anyway.

You should ask the people providing the process what the reason for failing is and why they use the layout file. Even when "UTF-8" is the default this line should not should not give problems.

Thanks all above, the process in question has been fixed now (something parsing related) and I no longer see the problem. However, the original question stands: is this line required or not ?

So the problem was a non doxygen problem. Best way is to try and see what happens in doxygen, when you use UTF-8 encoding anyway it, probably (confirmed with a quick test), won't make a difference
